# Kivy - on_press bind event to btn not work

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

```
import re
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from engine.common.modifycation import AlignedTextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorPicker

class EditorOperationAdd():

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditorOperationAdd, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        content = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        clr_picker = ColorPicker()

        infoBtn = Button(text='Add new button')
        content.add_widget(Label(text='color'))
        content.add_widget(clr_picker)
        content.add_widget(Label(text='Text'))
        #content.add_widget(AlignedTextInput(text='My Button', halign="middle", valign="center"))
       
        self.popup = Popup(title='Add new button editor box', content=content, auto_dismiss=False)

        content.add_widget(infoBtn)
        infoBtn.bind(on_press=self.localCall)
        clr_picker.bind(color=self.on_color)
        #infoBtn.bind(on_press=self.operationAdd)
        
        self.popup.open()

        infoBtn2 = Button(text='Add new button 2', on_press=self.localCall )
        content.add_widget(infoBtn2)
        ####################################################
        # Operation `Add`
        ####################################################

        self.addNewButtonGUIOperation()

    def localCall(self, obj, value):
        print("works man", obj)
        print("works man", value)

    # To monitor changes, we can bind to color property changes
    def on_color(self, instance, value):
        print( "RGBA = ", str(value) ) #  or instance.color
        print( "HSV = ", str(instance.hsv))
        print( "HEX = ", str(instance.hex_color))

    def operationAdd(self):
        print("Operation add.")
        self.popup.dismiss()

    def addNewButtonGUIOperation(self):
        print("empty")
        # self.localCall()
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to bind before add widget, Try this:

```
infoBtn2 = Button(text='Add new button 2' )
infoBtn2.bind(on_press=self.localCall())
content.add_widget(infoBtn2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `localCall` method doesn't match the arguments that the button press provides. It only passes the `Button` instance (unless you specify otherwise). Just change your `localCall` method to:

```
def localCall(self, button):
    print("works man", button)
```